# Question related to Hydration of Alkynes

Tags: organic-chemistry

There will be Markovnikov addition of water and hence —OH will be added to the carbon with triple bond having less number of hydrogen and —H will be added to the one having more number of hydrogen. Then the adduct will tautomerise to form the product corresponding to option A but the answer given is option B. Where am I going wrong? [image]

Comment: I think it is due to the greater intensity of negative inductive effect at beta carbon wrt ketone. And as there is no possibility of conjugation to take place,  inductive effect should dominate.

Comment: If indeed B is the answer, think about the carbonyl oxygen reacting with the mercurinium ion. [This is a terrible question. It should read,"Why is B formed and not A or why does B predominate over A?"]

Comment: BTW, there is water in this reaction.

Answer (score 3):

The mercuration of acetylene **1** leads to mercurinium ion **2**.<sup>[3](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11030-019-09930-x)</sup> Participation of the carbonyl oxygen via a five-membered transition state with hydration affords **3**. Protonation of this intermediate leads to aldehyde **4**, which undergoes exchange of mercury for hydrogen giving the product **5**. This mechanism is based on the observations of Stork and Borch<sup>[1](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja01059a047),[2](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ja01059a046)</sup> who observed that hydration of **6** involves carbonyl oxygen participation via a six-membered transition state affording a 1,5-diketone. In the case of **7**, a five-membered transition state provides a 1,4-diketone.
[image]
1) G. Stork and R. Borch, [*J. Am. Chem. Soc.*, **1964**, *86*, 935](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ja01059a046).
2) G. Stork and R. Borch, [*J. Am. Chem. Soc.*, **1964**, *86*, 936](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja01059a047).
3) For 5-endo-dig cyclizations, see: M. A. Sajid, et al., [*Molecular Diversity*, **2020**, *24*, 295.](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11030-019-09930-x)

Comment: (+1) So, Cl got no major role in product formation?

Comment: No! I suspect it may be a madeup problem or unpublished. A Chem. Abst. search did not find the reaction with or without chlorine.

Answer (score 2):

Due to -I effect from the carbonyl group and the halogen, not far enough for it to be negligible, the stability of the primary vinylic carbocation is counter-intuitively more than that of the secondary vinylic carbocation. Markonikov rule is applicable in absence of permanent electron shift effects, like resonance and inductive effects. The Markonikov rule, under these restrictions, translates into the stability of the carbocation, decided by the positive inductive effect of neighbouring carbons. As a clearer example, consider the hydration of acrolein,[image]

The reaction predominantly yields the primary alcohol, as opposed to the product predicted by the markonikov rule, which again is not applicable in presence of permanent electronic effects. Hope that helps!